# Why do I get "error: too few arguments to function ‘sock->ops->accept’"

Tags: c, sockets, linux-kernel, kernel-module, unix-socket

I am writing kernel module with sockets. When I try write code for accept connection I get:

"error: too few arguments to function ‘sock->ops->accept’
         ret = sock->ops->accept(sock, client_sock, 0);"

I looked into implementation of socket accept and there are only three arguments so I don't know what's going on.

```
struct socket *sock = NULL, *client_sock = NULL;
//some code here, create socket, bind, listen
ret = sock->ops->accept(sock, client_sock, 0);
```

I expect that it should works but it doesn't. Why do I get "too few arguments" error if in implementation are only three? How can I fix that?

Comment: Please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error output into the question (as text). There probably are informational notes that will tell you what the compiler expected. Also please take some time to refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The prototype of the `->accept()` handler was changed between kernel versions 4.10 and 4.11 by this commit: "[net: Work around lockdep limitation in sockets that use sockets](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=cdfbabfb2f0ce983fdaa42f20e5f7842178fc01e)".

As mentioned in user [MofX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2329264/mofx)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57354390/5264491), the `->accept()` handler has a fourth parameter `bool kern` in current kernel versions (since 4.11).  According to the commit description, this is analogous to the `kern` parameter passed in to `->create()`, and distinguishes whether `kernel_accept()` or `sys_accept4()` was the caller.  See the [commit description](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=cdfbabfb2f0ce983fdaa42f20e5f7842178fc01e) for details.

If you want your code to work for kernels both before and since 4.11, you will need to use conditional compilation:

```
#include <linux/version.h>

#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(4,11,0)
#define KV_ACCEPT_HAS_BOOL_KERN
#endif

#ifdef KV_ACCEPT_HAS_BOOL_KERN
    // your code needs to determine whether 'kern' should be false or true here...
    ret = sock->ops->accept(sock, client_sock, 0, kern);
#else
    ret = sock->ops->accept(sock, client_sock, 0);
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

There are four arguments in proto_ops::accept

```
struct proto_ops {
    ...
    int     (*accept)    (struct socket *sock,
                      struct socket *newsock, int flags, bool kern);
};
```

See: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/net.h#L147